Oscillation in opamp output
I wanted to build the hydrophone amplifier circuit shown in the LT1113 datasheet as a hobby.

I set up the circuit as specified. Instead of a hydrophone, I used PUI Audio's AB6505B piezo. However, when I measured the output of the circuit with an oscilloscope, I observed a continuous oscillation at a low frequency of 0.35Hz with an amplitude of 350mV at the output, as well as some noise. Thinking that the DC servo circuit was too slow, I made some modifications. I changed the C2 capacitor to 100nF. When the circuit was first powered on, it produced a damped oscillation with a large amplitude and stabilized for a while, then produced a smaller oscillation again.Every 3-4second it produced small oscillation. later When I replaced the 100nF with 150nF, the output of the circuit oscillated continuously at about 500mV. Similarly, when I changed C2 to 68nF, it also remained in continuous oscillation. I conducted all these measurements with the piezo sensor present. Without the piezo, there was noise around 300 mV at the output of the op-amp. In this case, I think it indicates that the op-amp is not functioning as desired. Both Opamp supplied with 12V -12V.
Does anyone have any thoughts on this? I would greatly appreciate any help!
Here you can see datasheet link:https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1113fc.pdf

See that note that says "R4C2 > R8CT"?
Your sensor has CT = 93000 pF, which gives a time constant of 9.3 seconds.
So you're going have to increase R4 and/or C2 until you have a time constant that's at least that high. If you keep R4 at 1 MΩ, you'll have to increase C2 to 10 µF.

Hi Dave, I tried this, but there was still oscillation.

Well, the note also says Ct between 100 and 5000 pF; maybe your sensor is simply outside the range of what it can handle without other adjustments, such as lowering the values of some of the resistors (starting with R8). Maybe it's time to do a full stability analysis of the circuit, which is where those criteria probably came from.
